# How to make custom theme in MEAN

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I am new in `MEAN` and going to create new website using `MEAN`.

I have created the package in `MEAN` using the command `mean package <package_name>`

I have also override the default templates using the `app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');` command in the `app.js` of my custom package, but the `MEAN` is still rendering my angular views within the `MEAN's` default layout.

The structure of my `MEAN` package folder is

```
packages
--core
----admin
----articles
----circles
----swagger
----system
----users
--custom
----<my_package>
------public
--------assets
--------controllers
--------directives
--------routes
--------services
--------views
------server
--------config
--------controllers
--------models
--------routes
--------views
------.bowerrc
------app.js
------bower.json
------package.json
----i18n
----theme
```

How can I render my own theme

Answer (score 2):

**To change the layout view to a different one than the default view**
In the routes folder under server parent folder, look for the file that has the function mapped to the route '/'.

Now look for that function in the controllers folder. Change the name of the view to render like this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res) {
res.render('differentviewfile', {
    user: req.user || null,
    request: req
});
```

};

**To change the look and feel of your site**
You can take advantage of numerous Bootstrap themes available out there. A lot of them are free. To use them, all you have to do is change the reference to the css file (you will find it in the server side view base layout page).

Change it from the default bootstrap file to a different one, and your whole app changes. For e.g. take a look at the 16 themes available at https://bootswatch.com You can reference the CDN link to any of the themes they have directly, or you can download the css file for it and add it to your own project.

If you want to add your own styles, you can of course create your own css file and add appropriate css styles.

Comment: I am asking about how to render our server side view base layout page even If I write the Hello in it, not for the how to create the UI.

Comment: Seems like total miscommunication between us. You had asked how to change the theme and I assumed you meant how to change the look and feel of your app (meaning different color combinations and styles).

Comment: You can alter the views in the server-> views folder to your liking by changing the html elements within it. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes its like, but is there no way to change the theme by creating my own layout in my package instead of changing the server layout?

Comment: You can create your own layout views too. Then you will need to change the routing to load your view instead of the current one. The route paths are in the config folder.

Comment: In which config file? there is no config in system folder or any descendent. Could you please elaborate or please edit your answer, So I can accept your answer as right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you injected a dependency to system package in your app.js file?

```
var MyCustomModule = new Module('mycustommodule');

/*
 * All MEAN packages require registration
 * Dependency injection is used to define required modules
 */
MyCustomModule.register(function(system, app, auth, database) {
```

You need to do that in order to wait until the system package is loaded. Then the line:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
```

will override the views config set in the system package :D